# JavaScript and Events - Best Practice

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I once read that the following coding technique is considered bad:

```
<a HREF="page.htm" onClick="alert('Hello World')">text link</a>
```

Basically, having these event handlers (like `onClick`) within the HTML tag is the wrong approach to use. What is the reason for this? What is this "bad" technique called? What is the "proper" way to do this?

Comment: quirksmode.org calls them *inline* event handlers. Have a look at these articles, the provide a very comprehensive introduction to event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an **inline event handler attribute**. (+1 chjj's answer for alternatives). It's generally considered ‘bad’ for a number of reasons:

- you're mixing small pieces of JavaScript syntax inline with HTML syntax:

  - when you have lots of these, especially when you have lots of elements that all contain essentially the same bit of code, it's harder to read and maintain the code;
  - you get nested-escaping horrors when you need to use special-to-HTML characters in your code:

eg.:

```
<a href="x.html" onclick="this.innerHTML= '&lt;em>I like &quot;fish &amp;amp; chips&quot;&lt;/em>';">
```

- properties of the target element *and all ancestor nodes* become variables, potentially hiding your own variables of the same name. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127037/disappearing-google-map/5127272#5127272) for background on this surprising and almost always unwanted behaviour;

  - this introduces spooky incompatibilities as browsers have different DOM properties;
  - and future browsers introducing new properties will potentially break your code.

Answer (score 6):

A couple reasons. It's essentially an alias to the DOM Level 1 interface of `element.onclick`, which only allows for one event listener.

Another reason is that it's simply philosophically wrong. It leads to poorly organized code: You're mixing a declarative language with a functional language which incorporates massive amounts of logic in its execution.

The proper way would be:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('hello world');
}, false); // required for old gecko
```

Or in IE:

```
element.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
  console.log('hello world');
});
```

or at the **very** least, use the DOM level 1 model:

```
element.onclick = function() {
  console.log('hello world');
};
```

(Also note, `alert` is bad practice, it will block execution of the entire page.)

Another reason would be, you don't get access to any kind of event object you would normally get as the first argument of the listener's callback. (You're essentially inside a callback when setting on[event] attributes, so I'm not sure if you can do arguments[0] or how different rendering engines implement it. It's very awkward, which is why it's best to bind events in JS-land.)

The final reason I can think of would be cross browser compatibility. You can't ever normalize an event interface for yourself if you're binding events in HTML.

Comment: @chjj re event argument: in an inline event handler attribute, you're expected to write just `event` to get the Event instance. In IE, this works because you get the global `window.event`; in other browsers it works because a local variable with the name `event` is created inside the inline code, as if you had written `function(event) { ... }` around it. This is poorly-documented and best avoided (I believe the difference in IE behaviour here is because MS originally didn't understand what was supposed to be going on either, only the referencing `event` was supposed to work...)

Comment: @bobince, yeah, I do vaguely remember something like that. It definitely seems like the type of thing various browsers would implement differently (or not at all). Hardly a thing to rely on.

Comment: @AdamF Why would they add a jQuery example if there's no reference for jQuery here? Also, event handling in jQuery is way easier. It's one of the more appealing things of using it, if you don't know about it, read the jQuery docs.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the official term, but it's not good practice because HTML should be pure markup, without mixing client side script directly into it.

Best practice is attaching the event in such way:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("MyLink").onclick = function() {
        alert('Hello World');
        return false;
    }
}
```

After giving the link ID `MyLink` for example.

Comment: Thanks! I could have sworn there was a proper term for this. The best I can recall is "old style JavaScript" (but that doesn't seem right).

Comment: No problem.. looks like Marcel found the term for us. :)

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is called [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and it basically means the separation of behaviour (JS) from structure (HTML), similar to how CSS is a separation of presentation from structure and also for the same reasons.