# Using a php variable in a setTimeOut function in a mouseover in an html tag

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables, settimeout

I have a php variable:

```
<?php
$imagename = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile());
?>
```

This is created in a loop. This loop displays some images.

When I hover over an image the onmouseover fires. This all goes okay.

The problem is:

```
onmouseover="myTimer=setTimeout('imageswitcher(<?php echo $imagename;?>)', 2000);"
```

The php doesn't work. Now I read something about ajax requests. But I have no idea what it is or how to use it. So I was hoping someone here could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have a million and one problems here besides the PHP variable things. Firstly, you really shouldn't be using the `onmouseover` attribute anymore. Take a look at [JavaScript & Events - Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888651/javascript-events-best-practice)

So to replicate your problem with **nicer** code, you would do something like this.

```
<!-- This should be in an external JS file -->
<script>
    // IE Event Listener "Polyfill"
    var addEvent = function(element, event, callback) {
        if (document.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(event, callback);
        } else {
            element.attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
        }
    };

    addEvent(document, 'load', function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('element');

        attachEvent(element, 'onmouseover', function() {
            myTimer = setTimeout('imageswitcher(<?php echo $imagename; ?>)', 2000);
        });
    }

</script>

<!-- Not an actual element, used for example purposes only -->
<element id="element"></element>
```

## Variables should be assigned using 'var'

---

Your next problem is that your assigning `myTimer` without `var`. Now, it's not likely to be causing the issue here, it's good to keep it in mind.

```
var myTimer = setTimeout('imageswitcher(<?php echo $imagename; ?>)', 2000);
```

## Function Strings

---

I don't know what your trying to do, but you're passing a string instead of a function to `setTimeout`. Let's fix that.

```
var myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    imageswitcher(<?php echo $imagename; ?>);
}, 2000);
```

## Addressing the issue

---

Now, let's address the actual issue here.

`$imagename` is probably a string, which you're not accounting for in your javascript. Let's fix that.

```
imageswitcher('<?php echo $imagename; ?>');
```

## Putting it all together

---

```
<!-- This should be in an external JS file -->
<script>

    var addEvent = function(element, event, callback) {
        if (document.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(event, callback);
        } else {
            element.attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
        }
    };

    addEvent(document, 'load', function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('element');

        attachEvent(element, 'onmouseover', function() {
            var myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                imageswitcher('<?php echo $imagename; ?>');
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
</script>

<!-- Not an actual element, used for example purposes only -->
<element id="element"></element>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Your solution worked :)
Thanks for the advice and for saving me some hours of trouble!

Comment: This is very likely a typo, but `attachEvent(element, 'onmouseover'...` should attach `mouseover` instead of `onmouseover`. OP very understandably defines a global `myTimer` instead of a local `var`, as that definition happens inside an implicit event handler function and that `myTimer` variable would have been inaccessible from anywhere if it were a local in that function.

Answer (score 1):

Embedding PHP values in Javascript code is most safely done with `json_encode()`, and since you're outputting in a HTML attribute, it would be wise to also put it through `htmlspecialchars()`; also, passing strings to `setTimeout` is discouraged practice, so you should pass an anonymous function there instead:

```
onmouseover="myTimer=setTimeout(function() { imageswitcher(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($imagename));?>) }, 2000);"
```

Comment: Hmm, this still doesn't do the trick :(
I commented on Dutchie432's answer what the content of `$imagename` could be->  http://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/test.jpg

Could this affect how i should do this?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I have put up a [working example](http://test.dev.lanzz.org/json_encode/index.php), and you can see its [source code](http://test.dev.lanzz.org/json_encode/index.txt).

Comment: NatIsGleek's solution worked. But i still want to thank you for taking the time to try and help me :)