# Jade button onclick

Tags: pug

I didn't find any normal manual to jade and need to know if I wrote my line of code properly.
I used [This converter](http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/) however

```
button#Black(style='width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: black;', type='submit', onclick='(color=', black='black')
```

Please lemme know if onclick part is right. Thanks in advance

Comment: That onClick looks weird (irrespective of Jade).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You should not style neither set event handlers on the HTML markup

It is widely considered a bad practice, both using [inline css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css) and using [js inline event handlers attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888651/javascript-events-best-practice).

---

### [See here the jade documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/README.md)

The syntax is not correct. You can [see here the jade attribute syntax](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/README.md#a6-9). Your line should be something as follows:

```
button#Black(
  type='submit'
  style='width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: black;'
  onclick="if you plan to use single quotes here, use double quotes outer"
)
```

**Note**: I splitted the lines for better reading but it is not necessary to do so.

Comment: +1 for splitting the line. Then you can also leave off the comma at the end.

Comment: like that? ' button#Black(style='width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: black;', type='submit', onclick="color='black'") '

Comment: No change the color to draw in canvas. But I did it already. Here            ' button#Black(style='width: 35px; height: 35px; background-color: black;', type='submit', onclick= 'javascript:color = "black"') '

Comment: @Koranse Ok, you were assigning a variable. Please consider voting up the answer if it was useful for you, or even accept it by clicking the tick under the answer's votes.