# How do I select a span content, using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next html.

I need to get a span text content of 'Jan' and '2017' in a onclick function.

I can´t use contains('Jan') or contains('2017') because that values can change at runtime.

I tried the next but no success.

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   function ClockClicked(){
   var smonth=$("span.spanmonth").filter(function() { return ($(this).text()) });
   var syear=$("span.spanyear").filter(function() { return ($(this).text()) });
   alert(smonth+'-'+ syear);
};

 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myclock">
     <div class="controls">
          <a class="pull-left">
            <div class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ClockClicked()">Click me</div>
          </a>
          <h4>
            <span  class="spanmonth" Jan></span> - <span class="spanyear" 2017></span> 
          </h4>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

html:

I have used this function:

Comment: Is this normal that "Jan" and "2017" are not between the > and < of the span ? if yes you should use data-month="Jan" and data-year="2017" then get it with the .data() function of jquery

Comment: I am using responsive calendar from http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/. The document says to use:<div class="responsive-calendar">
  <div class="controls">
      <a class="pull-left" data-go="prev"><div class="btn"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></div></a>
      <h4><span data-head-year></span> <span data-head-month></span></h4>
      <a class="pull-right" data-go="next"><div class="btn"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></div></a>
  </div><hr/>.  I only did changes to my needs. I add onclick and a class  to my needs. No other changes.

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Comment: OK, Sorry for  it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per statement *get a span text content of 'Jan' and '2017'* I am assuming HTML content is

```
<span class="spanmonth" >Jan</span> - <span class="spanyear">2017</span>
```

You need to use `.text()`. No need of using `.filter()`

```
var smonth=$("span.spanmonth").text();
var syear=$("span.spanyear").text();
alert(smonth+'-'+ syear);
```

I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event handler as *@Rory McCrossan* suggested.

Comment: I am using responsive calendar from http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/.  I am using the span copied from the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Firstly note that your HTML is invalid. The `Jan` and `2017` values should be wrapped in the `span` elements, not set as attributes of it - which itself is invalid.

Secondly it's better practice to use an unobtrusive event handler over the now outdated `on*` event attributes. Within that event handler you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element that raised the event and traverse the DOM to find the `span` you require. In this case, `closest()` and `find()` would suit your needs. Try this:

```js
$('.myclock .btn').click(function() {
  var $clock = $(this).closest('.myclock');
  var month = $clock.find('.spanmonth').text();
  var year = $clock.find('.spanyear').text();

  console.log(month, year);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclock">
  <div class="controls">
    <a class="pull-left">
      <div class="btn btn-primary">Click me</div>
    </a>
    <h4>
      <span  class="spanmonth">Jan</span> - <span class="spanyear" >2017</span>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation re `it's better practice to use an unobtrusive event handler over the now outdated on*` as I am interested to learn the background.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I can't find anything canonical at the moment, but here's a couple of references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888651/javascript-events-best-practice & https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/jquery-examples-and-best-practices/

Comment: I am using responsive calendar from http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/.  See my other comment above

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for that - I concur your point. I infact misread your reference to `on*` as meaning the jquery `$selector.on(eventname, function(){...})` approach was deprecated. For anyone new to jquery the smashingmagazine.com article is a good introduction to approach and style.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Your html is invalid as you have 'Jan' between the < and > tag instead of  text within the span.

In any case, you can try the filter -contains':

`$( "span.spanmonth").filter(":contains('2017')" );`

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: I am using responsive calendar from http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/.  See my other comment above

Comment: I can't use contains as explained above in uq question