# syntax difference in javascript function calling?

Tags: javascript, html, function, syntax

What is the difference between:

```
<div onclick="return function()"></div>
```

vs

```
<div onclick="function()"></div>
```

They seem to be doing the same thing for me and I am not sure which one to use.

Comment: Try to not use HTML event attributes at all. Get familiar with the traditional event model (pure js), and you'll understand what it means to return values from handlers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript onclick return functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814949/javascript-onclick-return-functionality)

Answer (score 10):

Take for example `<form onsubmit="return validate();">...` The submit will be cancelled if validate() returns false.

With `<form onsubmit="validate();">...` The submit will continue regardless of the return value of validate().

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation in words..

> One will **return** the value to the element which the attribute
> resides in, the other will not.

When you use `return function ()` the default click-method of the element will only be executed if `function ()` evaluates to a value that implicitly is converted to *true*.

If it yields *false* the evaluation of the click-event will halt after running the *onclick*-property.

---

In case of `onclick="function ()"` the default click-propery of the element will **always** be executed, no matter what the function returns.

---

#### Example snippets with detailed information of what is happening..

```
function some_func () { return false; }
```

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return some_func()">
  link #1
</a> <!-- user will never end up at google -->
```

<sup>if javascript is enabled in the browser, of course..</sup>

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="some_func()">
  link #1
</a> <!-- user will always end up at google -->
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference, if you write return, it will check if the return is true or false and will only take action if return is true. otherwise it will just process.