# why these two functions don't want to run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really don't know why these two functions - leave() & do() - don't run !

```
    function leave() 
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("x");
        if(x.value == "")
        {
            alert("please enter your name");
            x.focus();
        }
    }

    function do()
    {
        var y = document.getElementById("y");
        if (y.value = "enter your name here")
        {
            alert("enter your last name");
            y.focus();
            y.select();                
        }
    }
```

here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/BsHa2

thanks in advance

Comment: Post code **in the question itself**, don't just link. That's **why** the system prevented you from posting the jsfiddle link until you marked it up as code. Surely working around the system like that wasn't your best choice?

Comment: [jsFiddle: no connection between html and js? Can't call simple function from button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499783/jsfiddle-no-connection-between-html-and-js-cant-call-simple-function-from-but)

Comment: T.j. Crowder, sorry i didn't know that! 
but am i prevented from asking any question again ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, am i prevented from asking any question again ? and why !?

Comment: @OmarAhmed: Not that I know of, but I'm not a moderator (other than the way nearly all users are). Only (real) moderators can suspend or lock an account.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: he's referring to the question ban.

Comment: @OmarAhmed: take a look at [what to do if you are getting a "We are no longer accepting questions from this account" message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/2074608).

Answer (score 1):

you have 3 problems:

1- which is in your jsfiddle options you have chosen to wrap all your code in the `onLoad`, so the functions are not in the global context, you can fix it as I have in the code below.

2- this line would set the value to the value of y input:

```
if (y.value = "enter your name here")
```

change it to

```
if (y.value == "enter your name here")
```

3- the other probelm is `do` is a reserved word, **DO NOT USE** reserved word, although it would do what you want in some browsers.

```
window.leave = function leave() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById("x");
    if(x.value == "")
    {
        alert("please enter your name");
        x.focus();
    }
}

window.check = function check()
{
    var y = document.getElementById("y");
    if (y.value = "enter your name here")
    {
        alert("enter your last name");
        y.focus();
        y.select();                
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `if (y.value = "enter your name here")`

Answer (score 0):

First `do` is a keyword so you can't use it as a method name - rename it to something like `check`

Second for inline event hadndlers the methods must be in global scope - Select body/head in the second dropdown in left panel in the fiddle

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x6RU8/)

Answer (score 0):

`do` is a reserved keyword. You can't use it as function name. Rename it to something else.

Secondly, inline event handlers must be defined in global scope. In your fiddle you have to select **Wrap in head option**

Third, `=` is assignment operator, to compare either use `==` and `===`, error in line `(y.value = "enter your name here")`

Use

```
function do1()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/b7vLJ/)

Comment: LOL, yes i forgot that !! .. sorry fr your time and thanks anyway :)

Comment: @OmarAhmed, Glad I could help. I hope that I covered all bases

Answer (score 0):

`do` is a reserved keyword. You can't use it as function name.

Also, you have a mistake here:

```
if (y.value = "enter your name here")
```

you need to check for equality:

```
if (y.value === "enter your name here")
```

As an aside, you should really consider giving your variables meaningful names and using unobtrusive event handlers:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="input" id="firstName" size="20">
    <br/>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" size="20" value="enter your name here">
    <input type="button" id="check" value="Check!">
</form>

var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName"),
    lastName = document.getElementById("lastName"),
    checkButton = document.getElementById("check");

firstName.onblur = function(){
  if (this.value === ""){
    alert("please enter your name");
    this.focus();
  }  
}

check.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (lastName.value === "enter your name here") {
      alert("enter your last name");
      lastName.focus();
    }
}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/74hXG/)**