# deleting an element with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete an element in a ul (list item) like so using only javascript. since I am dynamically generating the html, I am trying to set the onclick as I create it below. However when I try to click (see fiddle) elements are not getting deleted. relevant functions below:

```
var appendHTML = function (el) {
    var list = document.getElementById("events");
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredDates.length; i++) {
        var listItem = filteredDates[i].name;
        listItem.className = "event-list";
        listItem.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteEvent()");
        list.appendChild(listItem);
    }
};


var deleteEvent = function () {
    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    var ul = listItem.parentNode;
    //Remove the parent list item from the ul
    ul.removeChild(listItem);
    return false;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/youngfreezy/7jLswj9b/5/

Comment: The code you posted here and the one in your fiddle don't match at all. How do you expect us to help you if you have two different versions of your code and we don't know which one to look at.

Comment: Even the original version is different from what you posted here. I guess https://jsfiddle.net/youngfreezy/7jLswj9b/1/ is the one that you posted here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first problem was that you had the "deleteEvent" in your html, jsFiddle doesn't like it.

second problem was that you took the wrong element in the deleteEvent so the parent was incorrect as well.

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7jLswj9b/7/

```
    var deleteEvent = function (ev) {
      var listItem = ev.target;
      var ul = listItem.parentNode;
      //Remove the parent list item from the ul
      ul.removeChild(listItem);
        return false;
    }

 var list = document.getElementById("events");
list.addEventListener("click",deleteEvent,false);
```

Comment: *"jsFiddle doesn't like it."* It's not that a tool can have feelings. You could at least explain the issues properly.

Comment: @FelixKling , inline click events are valid and would have worked outside of jsfiddle, although they are not recommended.

Comment: It also works inside jsFiddle if setup correctly. Whether or not it's recommended is a different issue.

Comment: I didn't know there is that option to set it "correctly", but criticizing the answer due to a specific tool issue is a different issue as well...

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer for jsFiddle issues, I'm criticizing it for not providing any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `onclick` attribute to set event code as a string, the `this` context gets lost.

The best way to register event handlers is via `addEventListener`:

```
listItem.addEventListener("click", deleteEvent);
```

---

As a fallback, set your event code as a function instead:

```
listItem.onclick = deleteEvent;
```

This is discouraged as you can only set 1 event handler per event this way.

---

If you really really *have* to set the code Inline, pass the value of `this` via an argument:

```
<ul id="events" onclick="deleteEvent(this)">...</ul>

function deleteEvent(element) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for explaining the different ways to do it and pros/cons!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your jsFiddle and your code.

#### Scope of the event handler

You are using an [*inline event handler*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html). Inline event handlers are executed in global scope. However, because the fiddle by default wraps your JavaScript code inside a function, `deleteEvent` *is not* global. The console shows the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

There are three ways to solve this:

- [Make the function global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5786851/218196).
- Setup your fiddle [to put / run the code at the end of the bod](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14499783/218196)y, not "on load".
- [Use a different way to bind the event handler](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html).

#### `this` inside the event handler

Because you are calling the function as `deleteEvent()`, [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) won't refer to the DOM element that triggered the event. It will refer to `window`, the global object, which doesn't have a `parentNode` property.

If you use a different way to bind the handler, as suggested above, then that problem might solve itself. Otherwise, you have to call `deleteEvent` in such a way that `this` refers to the element:

```
onclick="deleteEvent.call(this)"
```

Of course you could also change the definition of `deleteEvent` to accept the element as argument instead.

However, in your fiddle you actually attached the event handler to the `<ul>` element, not to each `<li>` element. In that case you have to pass the event object to function instead and get the original target from it:

```
onclick="deleteEvent(event)"
```

and

```
var deleteEvent = function (event) {
  //Remove the parent list item from the ul
  event.target.parentNode.removeChild(event);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/v1xj92gg/)

#### Wrong node reference

It seems you are deleting the wrong node in `deleteEvent`. `listItem` will actually be the `<ul>` element, because that's the parent of the clicked element. Consequently, `ul` will be the parent of the `<ul>` element.

Since `this` already refers to the `<li>` element, there is need for `listItem` here, and `ul` should be `this.parentNode`. In shorter form:

```
var deleteEvent = function () {
  //Remove the parent list item from the ul
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

#### `return false` has no effect

`return false` is often used to prevent the default action of the event. However, clicking on a `li` element has no default action. Furthermore, the value has to be return from the event handler. `deleteEvent` is not your event handler, it is called by your event handler. So if you want to return its return value, you have to do exactly that:

```
listItem.setAttribute("onclick", "return deleteEvent()");
```

But again, you should prefer a different of binding the event handler.

#### Invalid node creation

In the code in your question you are trying to call `setAttribute` on an arbitrary object and try to append an arbitrary object to a DOM element. That won't work. You have to use `document.createElement` to create a new element:

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
```

It seems you are doing this correctly in your fiddle.

Comment: very interesting solution. that deletes the entire ul and not individual "li"s though!

Comment: @devdropper87: Well, that's the logic you have in `deleteEvent`. So I guess the third issue is that your logic in there is incorrect.

Comment: Also the code you posted here is different than the code in your fiddle.  Here you are binding the handler to each `li` element, in your fiddle you attached the handler to the `<ul>` element.

Comment: @devdropper87 in my answer above I have corrected your code so you can see what was wrong