# How do I get JSFiddle's window.onload event to fire?

Tags: javascript, function, onload, jsfiddle

I want to create a function that will execute when my page loads.  Normally I would put this function in the body's onload attribute.  I'm a little unsure how to do that in JSFiddle.  I have this in my script ...

```
window.onload=function(){ alert('hi'); }
```

but nothing happens when I load my page -- https://jsfiddle.net/xx77tzn3/3/ .  How do I execute a function in JSFiddle when the body loads?

Comment: jsFiddle has a configuration option to put all the code in the JavaScript pane in either a "load" handler, or in the body. Click on the little button in the upper right corner of the panel.

Comment: The default is to put your code in a "load" handler, so when the "load" event fires, and you set up another "onload" function, it'll never run because there won't be another "load" event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsFiddle: no connection between html and js? Can't call simple function from button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499783/jsfiddle-no-connection-between-html-and-js-cant-call-simple-function-from-but)

Comment: @Pointy, what if I don't want to put all the JS pane code in the onload, but rather, define a function in there and then have that function execute in the onload?

Comment: @Teemu, I think the JSFiddle settings have changed since 2015, when taht question was posted.  I don't see a "No wrap (Head)" setting anywhere.

Comment: Yep, they have a new layout, the settings are still the same. There it is, in the "Load type" drop down, the third option ... Take a look at the top right corrner of JS pane, There you can see a button with text "JAVASCRIPT" and a gear icon, click that button and you'll find what you need.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the new location of the setting.  Taht solved it.