# jsfiddle: how to change the way the JavaScript block is loaded to no wrap (head)

Tags: javascript, html

My jsfiddle doesn't work for a href="javascript"

[image]

Here it is said [jsFiddle: no connection between html and js? Can't call simple function from button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499783/jsfiddle-no-connection-between-html-and-js-cant-call-simple-function-from-but)

> change the way the JavaScript block is loaded to no wrap (head)

but I can't see any option like that in jsfiddle settings!

[image]

Comment: Click the "JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS) " text. While you can use no wrap to make sure your function is seen, strongly consider using a proper event listener instead of using inline handlers and polluting the global scope

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks that works - my purpose is not about event listener I know there's better way, it was just about jsfiddle.