# How to prevent commandButton from executing action when onclick method return false

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2

i'm working with primefaces commandButton with onclick and action, i want to prevent onclick from execute action method when onclick function return false

CommandButton :

```
  <p:commandButton value="calc"action="#{bean.actionMethod()}"  oncomplete="DataReturn(xhr, status, args)" onclick="javaScriptOnclickmethod();">
          </p:commandButton>
```

JavaScript :

```
function javaScriptOnclickmethod(){

    var code = document.getElementById("form:idS").value;
    if(code.trim() !== '') {
    return true;
    } else {
             return false;

        }
}
```

what should i do to stop on the onlick function when returning false

Comment: You're not returning the result of function call in `onclick`.

Comment: @BalusC please what should i do to get this to work ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814949/javascript-onclick-return-functionality

Comment: onclick="return javaScriptOnclickmethod();" i did this but when the method return false it reload the whole page, i don't know why !! @BalusC

Comment: Press F12 and check JS console for clues. Big chance it just threw a JS error.

Comment: nothing happen on the JS console, it just reload the page when the onclick function return true !  @BalusC

Comment: That's normal behavior. Perhaps you mixed true and false?

Comment: function sendAutCptValuesToBean(){
 PF('start').show();
    var cdRamss = document.getElementById("form1:idrs_input").value;
    if(cdRamss.trim() !== '') {
    document.getElementById("form1:cdRmsHD").value = cdRamss;
    } else {
     PF('start').hide(); 
             alert("Ramasseur Vide !");
             return false;
   
        }
}  and my commandButton is like  <p:commandButton value="Calculer" icon="ui-icon-refresh" id="clcTxt" action="#{jsonJsf.calculTaxation()}" onclick="return sendAutCptValuesToBean();">   @BalusC