# How to create a confirmation popup for class.DeleteView

Tags: python, django, popup

I am looking to create a confirmation popup window whenever the delete button is clicked. It currently is functional and immediately deletes. Here is some of my code:
views.py:

```
class patientDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = patient
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patients:index')
```

index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'patients:patient-delete' patient.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="{{ patient.id }}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

and my urls.py

```
# /patients/patient/pk/delete
url(r'patient/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.patientDelete.as_view(), name='patient-delete'),
```

I have searched left, right and center and dont really understand most of it. I have been using a lot of tutorials to help me here and am quite new to django. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the javascript [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) method inside the `onclick` attribute of your `<button>`:

```
<button type="submit" class="..." onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
```

You can read more about how `return` inside `onclick` works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814949/javascript-onclick-return-functionality).