# any bad influence of onclick instead of using seperate javascript of same script <script>

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have been using onclick to execute my javascript code for a long time, but I was told by many folks not to use this inline javascript, and I don't know the disadvantage of it

Comment: I wonder whether any short comings of inline javascript @Gyandeep

Comment: Maybe after reading http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html and http://www.digital-web.com/articles/separating_behavior_and_structure_2/, you will have a better idea of the issues.

Comment: You should not use inline javascript in your HTML file, but better use a library like jQuery which allows you to set the events in a separate file.

Comment: @htatche: You don't need jQuery to bind event handlers with/in JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling I never said you do :)

Comment: @htatche: You kind of did. "jQuery allows you to do X" can imply that X is not possible otherwise.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry for naming jQuery then.

Comment: @Quentin: I might just move my answer over there, what do you think? The answers there don't seem to cover what I explained.

Comment: @FelixKling — Yours is the better answer. I'd lean towards doing that, especially if it looks like this one will be closed.

Comment: I copied my answer to the other question and will delete mine here. As for the problem mentioned in one of your comments, check out event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Comment: @Quentin: Ah actually [bobince linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler#comment8273183_6941483) [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127037/disappearing-google-map/) which exactly explains what I wrote. Anyways, I'll leave it now as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the difference between these, the second is far clearer and cleaner, because it separates the behaviour from the content.

## Method 1:

### index.html:

```
<div onclick="alert('div clicked!');this.innerHTML='Clicked!';">Not clicked...</div>
```

## Method 2:

### index.html:

```
<div id="123">Not clicked...</div>

<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

### js/scripts.js:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("123");

elem.onclick = function(e) {
    alert('div clicked!');

    this.innerHTML = 'Clicked!';
};
```